# PHP session id in cookie and storage

Tags: php, session, encryption

I've read multiple comments about encrypting PHP session data, in case it is stored in a temp directory that is available on multiple accounts on a shared server. However, even if the *data* is encrypted, session_start() still generates filenames containing the session_id.  For example,

```
sess_uivrkk2c5ksnv2hnt5rc8tvgi5
```

, where uivrkk2c5ksnv2hnt5rc8tvgi5 is the same session id I found in the cookie my browser received.

How is this problem typically addressed / could someone point me to an example?  All of the simple examples I've found only address encrypting the data, not changing the filename.

Just to see what would happen, I made a SessionHandler wrapper that would do an MD5 hash on the $session_id variable before passing it on to its parent function, but that did not work.  Instead, I ended up with two files: a blank one (with session_id as a part of its name) and a full one (with an MD5'ed session_id).  Also, there was the problem of close() not accepting session_id as a parameter, so I couldn't pass it on to its parent.

EDIT: I 'm learning about php sessions, this isn't for a live commercial site, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in some scenarios (i.e. a very incompetently configured server - although these do unfortunately exist)  on a shared server your session data may be readable by other people. Trying to hide the session files by changing their names serves no useful purpose - this is described as "Security through Obscurity". Go and Google the phrase - it is usually described as an oxymoron.

If your question is how do you **prevent** other customers accessing your session data on a badly configured server then the sensible choices (in order of priority) are:

- switch service provider
- use a custom session handler to store the data somewhere secure (e.g. database) There are lots of examples on the web - quality varies
- use a custom session handler to encrypt the data and use file storage. Again you don't need to write the code yourself - just scrutinize any candidates

If you want to find out if your provider might be a culprit - just have a look at the value of **FILE**. Does it look as if you have access to the root filesystem? Write a script which tries to read from outside your home directory. If you can't then the provider may have set an open_basedir restriction (it is possible to get around this - again Google will tell you how).

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned in the post that I was doing this as a learning exercise. I know that if I did run into this problem, I would want to switch service providers & ideally use a good session handling library / well tested code.

To clarify, I wasn't trying to "hide the session files by changing their names".  I was trying to remove the session_id variable from the session file name.  

I have seen several posts talking about encrypting session data, but if you have the session id, you have full access to the user's account anyway.

Comment: Eh? If you remove the session id from the filename then how do you find it again? How does this prevent people from reading the files?

Comment: Well I tried doing a one-way hash.  So someone visits a page on the website, and they're given a cookie containing a session id.  The $session_id from the cookie is passed through a hashing function to get the new number / character string that's used in the filename.  The trouble is, I can't seem to get this to work using the SessionHandler wrapper... but I don't know if that's even the right way to go about this problem, which is why I posted here.  Encrypting the data in the files is a separate problem, and I've found a few examples on how to do it.

Comment: If you want to know why your code isn't doing what you expect then post it (as a new question)